# File sharing always given authentication errors

Tags: finder, network, sharing, smb, file-sharing

I've used file sharing on all my Macs in the past, and it works great. I got a new M1 Mac Mini, and as usual, I tried to enable File Sharing on it.

Every time I attempt to connect to it from other Mac (e.g. my MacBook Pro), it gives an authentication error. Interestingly, it behaves differently when the password is wrong vs when it's correct, but disallows me in either case.

1. Attempting to connect via Finder with the correct username (`Alex`), but wrong password: it "shakes" the window, as expected.
2. Attempting to connect via Finder as guest (which should be allowed): it "shakes" the window
3. Attempting to connect via Finder using my AppleID: it "shakes" the window
4. Attempting to connect via Finder with the correct username/password: it doesn't shake the window, but gives this error dialogue box instead:

   [image: Access to your account on the Server "Mini" has been denied. Contact your system administrator for more information.]
5. Attempting to connect over CLI with the correct password:

   ```sh
   $ mount_smbfs //Alex@mini.home ~/Desktop/tmp/
   Password for mini.home: <correct password>
   mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Authentication error
   ```
6. Attempting to connect over CLI with the wrong password:

   ```sh
   $ mount_smbfs //Alex@mini.home ~/Desktop/tmp/
   Password for mini.home: <wrong password>
   mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error #
   ```

   Interestingly, the error message is different.

##### Other info

1. Screen sharing works just fine, with the exact same username/password.
2. Here are my account's advanced settings:

   [image]
3. Here's is the File Sharing portion of the Sharing preference pane:

   [image]

   And here's the page that opens when you click "Options..."

   [image]

##### Troubleshooting steps I've tried

1. Restarting the (server) Mac.
2. Turning off sharing and turning back on.
3. Changing the account password (to the same value as before).
4. Checking the logs in `Console.app`, using search queries like `any: smb` and `any: share`. I couldn't find anything interesting.
5. I have also tried all the steps above using the "Full name" (`Alexander Momchilov`) instead of the "Account name" (`Alex`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried mounting the shared folder, that is: `mount_smbfs "//Alex@mini.home/Alexander Momchilov's Public Folder" ~/Desktop/tmp/` (spaces  in the share name may be a problem, I'd recommend that you test with a directory without spaces, too)? Have you tested whether connecting locally over CLI works, that is, does running `mount_smbfs //Alex@mini.home ~/Desktop/tmp/` (or `mount_smbfs "//Alex@mini.home/Alexander Momchilov's Public Folder" ~/Desktop/tmp/`) on the M1 Mac Mini work? Are all Macs on the same network?

Comment: Yes they are all on the same network. I think I also tried connecting via local host directly on the Mac mini, but that was different than the commands you listed. I’ll give them a shot later and report back

Comment: I had this issue and In could not get it to work until I made sure the time was correct on both computers.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by resetting my password to the same one. Then went back to Sharing, going to Options, Clicking on "Share files and folders using SMB", then clicking on the check mark by my user name in the grid at bottom of the window. It prompts you to confirm that you want this user to be able to share/access those folders. Then it'll work.

It's not obvious bcs you assume that part of the screen only applies to Windows File Sharing and not the Samba stuff.

Comment: That was what worked for me, thanks!